# How to form below object?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I need to send json object to server which is similar to below

```
[{"like_ids":[3,6,12]},{"dislike_ids":[3,5,6]}]
```

when i tried it is bit different than actual if anyone point me where i miss Thank you

my code :

```
     var params : [String : Any] = [:]
    params["like_ids"] = likes
    params["dislike_ids"] = disLikes
```

likes and dislikes are Arrays and result something like this

```
["like_ids": [3520, 958, 2138], "dislike_ids": [959, 6732, 10]]
```

Comment: Don’t use Any in your dictionary, use the real type instead and then you can use JSONEncoder to encode to json

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks for the replay can you elaborate

Comment: Both of the values are int arrays so use that instead of Any, [String: [Int]]

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used Swift in a long time but here we go...

Create structs for like_ids and dislike_ids
(I would imagine you'd want a user struct that includes both,
but this is to answer your question specifically.

```
/* Structs */

struct likes: Codable {
    var like_ids = [Int]()
}

struct dislikes: Codable {
    var dislike_ids = [Int]()
}

// Create the instances you want in your json result
var like_ids1 = likes(like_ids: [3, 6, 12])
var dislike_ids1 = dislikes(dislike_ids: [3, 5, 6])

// This is an encoder, which in general allows you to convert Swift objects to json
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
// Encode the created instances of our struct 
let data_like = try encoder.encode(like_ids1)
let data_dislike = try encoder.encode(dislike_ids2)

// Build string from encoded struct data
let json_likes = String(data: data_like, encoding: .utf8)!
let json_dislikes = String(data: data_dislike, encoding: .utf8)!
```

And I'm guessing you wanted likes and dislikes as separate objects initially so either add the strings together as you wanted or do the same as above with something like

```
struct feedback: Codable {
    var like_ids = [Int]()
    var dislike_ids = [Int]()
}

// and move on from here
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your required JSON, it is an array of JSON objects. So, try this code it will return exactly what you want.

This is how you formate your data.

```
var likeIds = [3,6,12]
var dislikeIds = [3,5,6]

var resutlDic = [String: Any]()
var finalResutlDic = [[String: Any]]()

params["like_ids"] = likeIds
resutlDic["dislike_ids"] = dislikeIds

finalResutlDic.append(resutlDic)

print(finalResutlDic.jsonStringRepresentation)
```

This is an extension of Array to convert Dictionary array to JSON string.

```
   extension Array {
      var jsonStringRepresentation: String? {
          do {
              let jsonData: Data = try  JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self, options: [])
              if  let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding:  String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
            return jsonString as String
              }
        
          } catch let error as NSError {
              print("Array convertIntoJSON - \(error.description)")
          }
          return nil
      }
  }
```

The following is the result of this code.

```
Optional("[{\"like_ids\":[3,6,12],\"dislike_ids\":[3,5,6]}]")
```